# Second ajax select rebuilt by first does not fire

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a form with 3 select fields. Selecting a value from the first should result in the second becoming populated, and this works. Similarly, when making a selection in the second, the third should be populated, however the second field never fires.

When the ajax callback from the first field returns the second field, the markup for the second field contains the ajax callback, which does not fire.

Here is the code:

```
   public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

      $config = $this->config('my.settings');

      $form = [];        

      $options = _get_list();

      $form['instances'] = [
        '#type' => 'details',
        '#title' => $this->t('Instances'),
        '#open' => false,
      ];

        $form['instances']['first'] = [
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#title' => 'First',
          '#options' => $options,
          '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::populateSecond',
            'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => 'edit-second',
            'progress' => [
              'type' => 'throbber',
              'message' => $this->t('Loading...'),
            ],
          ]
        ];

        $form['instances']['second'] = [
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#title' => 'Second',
          '#options' => '',
          '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-second">',
          '#suffix' => '</div>',
          '#validated' => TRUE,
        ];

        $form['instances']['third'] = [
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#title' => 'Third',
          '#options' => '',
          '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-third">',
          '#suffix' => '</div>',
          '#validated' => TRUE,
        ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  public function populateSecond(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $selectedValue = $form_state->getValue('first');
    if ($selectedValue) {
      $second = _get_second_list($selectedValue);

      $form['instances']['second'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Second',
        '#options' => $second,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-second">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#validated' => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::populateThird',
          'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
          'event' => 'change',
          'wrapper' => 'edit-third',
          'progress' => [
            'type' => 'throbber',
            'message' => $this->t('Loading...'),
          ],
        ]
      ];

      return $form['instances']['second'];
    }

  }

  public function populateThird(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $selectedFirst = $form_state->getValue('first');
    $selectedSecond = $form_state->getValue('second');
    if ($selectedFirst && $selectedSecond) {
      $third = _get_third_list($selectedFirst, $selectedSecond);
      $form['instances']['third'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Third',
        '#options' => $third,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-third">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#validated' => TRUE,
      ];

      return $form['instances']['third'];
    }

  }
```

Here is an example of the 'if' statement that precedes each form field in buildForm in the final working version.

```
       if (!empty($form_state->getUserInput()['first'])) {
          $second = _get_second_list($form_state->getUserInput()['first']);
        }
        else {
          $second = NULL;
        }
```

and then, in field 'second', as an example:

```
    #options = $second;
```

Comment: In your initial second, try adding an empty ajax `'#ajax' => [],`. Just something I would try,  I don't know if it will fix your problem.

Comment: Is that code in the ajax callback? If not, it will not work. All form elements need to be created in the form definition (or an alter hook).

Comment: I had tried that originally with the full #ajax entry, and just tried again with the placeholder, probably thinking the same thing, that maybe the callback registration needs to happen upstream or it's too late. But there's no change.

Comment: @Jaypan The code above up thru the return is from the buildForm of the form class. I'll add the initial lines there.

Comment: You are building form elements in your ajax callbacks `populateSecond()` and `populateThird()`. This won't work. You need to add those form elements in the buildForm() method. You can use a conditional like `if (!empty($form_state->values())` to determine if it is initial form build, or an ajax submission.

Comment: Then how does the callback provide the options? It targets a div for replacement...how can I wrap just the options in a div instead of the entire field?

Comment: You can get the submitted value from the form state.

Comment: I think I’m following you... so get the submitted value from the form state and use it in the if statement to call the function that builds the options. So with that the Ajax callback provided nothing but the return trip needed to fire the if statement?

Comment: Yes, that worked. I construct the complete field now in buildForm() rather than in the callback. Before fields 2 and 3 I have something like the 'if' statement I added above at the end of my description, and in the callbacks I simply return the field, the important point being that the field has already been built in buildForm, not in the callback. Also, I note that I found success getting the user-selected value from $form_state->getUserInput.
@Jaypan Can you paste something in as an answer so I can select it?